Making Autosize All Columns the default view every time attribute tables are opened in QGIS
At QGIS 3.34.6, attribute table column widths can be manually adjusted so that all values can be seen, using the Autosize dropdown:

Question:
How can I set QGIS so that Autosize All Columns is the default view every time any attribute table is opened?

Maybe a longer term solution...
I had a look on the QGIS issue list and the original feature request for the "autosize all columns" context menu was never closed (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41108).
So, I added this suggestion there... and there has been a reaction to it, so hopefully it gets implemented.

I once needed something similar and what I did was this:
To set the column auto-size behavior:
def focusChanged(old, new):
    if isinstance(new, QTableView) and new.parent().parent().parent().parent().objectName().startswith('QgsAttributeTableDialog'):
        header = new.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        columns = [new.columnWidth(column) for column in range(header.count())]
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)
        for id, width in enumerate(columns):
            new.setColumnWidth(id, width)

    
app = QgsApplication.instance()
app.focusChanged.connect(focusChanged)

To unset it:
app.focusChanged.disconnect(focusChanged)

I couldn't find any signal that's send when an attribute table is open, so all what I found was the focusChanged signal, so you'll need to focus the dialog to trigger the column auto-size. I took many ideas from this post.
